# Cygwin ssh - Identity file not accessible

Tags: file, ssh, cygwin, identity, accessible

I've been trying to make ssh connection using Cygwin, but it doesn't recognize my id_rsa public key file.

My command lines are as follows:

```
$ssh XXX@XXX -i /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa
Warning: Identity file /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa not accessible: No such file or directory.
Permission denied (publickey,XXX).
```

(Sorry, I used XXX for the private information.)

I copied my .pub file to C:\cygwin\home\XXX.ssh folder. But it still spits out the same error message.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

**Background**

Most cygwin executables, map Unix path `/home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa` to Windows path `C:\cygwin64\home\XXX\.ssh\id_rsa`. Except that ssh.exe maps the same Unix path to Windows path `C:\home\XXX\.ssh\id_rsa`.

That is if you do `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa`, it will print out the contents of `C:\cygwin64\home\XXX\.ssh\id_rsa`, but if you do `ssh XXX@XXX -i /home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa` it will try to read the key from `C:\home\XXX\.ssh\id_rsa`.

I assume this is bug in Cygwin. In any event, this is a workaround that worked for me (on Windows 10 and the latest version of Cygwin as of October 2020).

**Solution**

Open Administrator command prompt. Go to `C:\` and issue the command `mklink /D home c:\cygwin64\home`

That's it.

But for me tat least, once I solved the above problem, I started getting the problem described in this Superuser question https://superuser.com/questions/1296024/windows-ssh-permissions-for-private-key-are-too-open. I used the solution from the most upvoted answer and ssh finally worked for me.

Comment: I just ran into this problem today.  After some investigation I realized my issue (and maybe yours) was that I didn't install openssh in Cygwin, so running `which ssh` in Cygwin output `/cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH/ssh` instead of `/usr/bin/ssh`.  After installing openssh in Cygwin everything started working.

Answer (score 1):

From your post it looks like SSH is looking for `/home/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa` and is not finding it. Ensure that the .pub file you copied is named correctly and has the right permissions.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your input. But I do have "full control" for the permission of this .pub file. It's not in incorrect file name either.

Comment: It's actually looking for a file with the specific name `id_rsa`, not id_rsa.pub or anything else ending in ".pub". And the file should be the _private_ key file. the .pub file is the _public_ key file, which is not what it's looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the option before the hostname...